# VBSCript to retrieve links from a google.com page

Tags: internet-explorer, object, vbscript

What I am doing is this:

1. Load www.google.com
2. type something in Input Box to search Google.com
3. and then retrieve the links provided by google in a text file.

I tried the script below but it does not return the "Links" provided by Google:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = TRUE
ie.Navigate("https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-  ab&q=my+sa+fria&oq=my+sa+fria&gs_l=hp.3...136.425.0.1178.5.4.0.0.0.2.318.916.0j2j1j1.4.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.ILEhJPZdulQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bmk&fp=aceecfc5e1faf854&biw=1366&bih=487")
Do until ie.ReadyState = 4
WScript.Sleep 50
Loop

set urls = ie.document.all.tags("a")
 For x = 0 to (urls.length)-1
 wscript.echo urls(x).innerHTML & " : " & urls(x).href
Next
wscript.echo "Number of URLs:", urls.length, vbNewline
```

Answer (score 1):

The search results are in `<h3>` tags, so you can use this information to distinguish them from other links on the page. Try this:

```
searchUrl   = "http://www.google.co.in/search?q="
searchTerms = Array("my", "sa", "fria")

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate searchUrl & Join(searchTerms, "+")

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
  WScript.Sleep 50
Loop

Set results = ie.document.all.tags("h3")
For Each anchor In results.children.tags("a")
  WScript.Echo anchor.href
Next
WScript.Echo "Number of results:", results.Length, vbNewline
```